# How to use equalTo() query function on a child which is an array

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Json Tree for Teachers database

```
{  "Teachers":
        {
          "Teacher_id" : {
            "email" : "teacher1@something.com",
            "name" : "teacher1",
            "Subjects" : {0 : "Maths",
                         1 : "science"
                         },
            "Subject_Exp-in-years" :{ 0:"Maths_2",
                                      1:"Science_4"
                                    }
            },
           "Teacher_id" : {
            "email" : "teacher2@something.com",
            "name" : "teacher2",
            "Subjects" : {0 : "Geography",
                          1 : "science"
                         },
            "Subject_Exp-in-years" :{ "Geography_5",
                                      "Science_1"
                                    }
          }
}
```

How can I get Set of Teachers who teach Science

I have used  the query

```
var db_ref=firebase.database().ref();
    db_ref.child("Teachers").orderByChild("Subjects").equalTo("Science")
```

How can I check if a value is present in an array in the database by querying functions?

Comment: You want to check the value using the firebase query? Or you want to check the value using an array?

Comment: Is the list of subjects known when you're creating the app? Or is this something that the user can enter in the app as they see fit?

Comment: UmarZaii I want to check if that subject is present in  subjects array  through firebase methods

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen those subjects can be added dynamically by the User

Comment: In that case this is a categorization problem. To implement those on Firebase you should keep an inverted mapping, from subjects to teachers. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Hi frank so how do i make an index for both experience and subject where i can query for all the teachers who teach science and have an experience of 3 or more  years in science

Answer (score 0):

When using `.orderByChild("Subjects").equalTo("Science")` doesn't work because none of the `Subjects` node children is equal to `Science`. So in order to solve this, I recomand you to change a little bit your database structure like this:

```
{  "Teachers":
    {
      "Teacher_id" : {
        "email" : "teacher1@something.com",
        "name" : "teacher1",
        "Subjects" : {Maths: true,
             science: true
             },
```

As you can see i have changed the childrens of `Subjects` with: `Maths: true` and `science: true`. To check if a value is present under a node, just use `exists()` function on that node.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex but how do i get the teacher node if i get child of subjects . Is there a way to use orderByChild() from Teacher node

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for the answer . How do i retrieve Teacher node by using orderByChild on Subjects node .

Comment: Using the exact database structure as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to read each of the element in an array.

When you read them one by one, you can include if else statement to check whether the value that you want existed or not. Let,s say the value is `JOHN`.

```
var index;
var arraylist = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (index = 0; index < arraylist.length; ++index) {
    if(arraylist[index] = "JOHN") {
        console.log(arraylist[index] + "is in the array");
    };
}
```